# log4net log file per thread null.log file

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net

I've used other posts here to get this far. But I've got an irritant I can't seem to resolve.  I need a logger for my main process, then a separate logger for each thread I kick off. Test example below works well except that I get a `main.log` (which works as expected), but also a file created `[null].log` (that's empty). Where's that `[null].log` coming from ?  (Thought that posting the whole thing might provide another complete working example of these 'per thread logs' when searching).

```
<log4net>
  <logger name="ThreadLogger">
    <appender-ref ref="ThreadAppender"/>
    <level value="ALL"/>
  </logger>
    <logger name="MainLogger">
      <appender-ref ref="MainAppender"/>
      <level value="ALL"/>
  </logger>
  <appender name="ThreadAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\Temp\%property{LogName}.log" />
    <immediateFlush value="true"/>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
  </appender>
  <appender name="MainAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\Temp\main.log"/>
    <immediateFlush value="true"/>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
  </appender>
</log4net>

class Program
{
        private static ILog mainlogger = null; //log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MainLogger");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            mainlogger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MainLogger"); //(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            mainlogger.Debug("Main thread start");
            while (true)
            {
                mainlogger.Debug("main thread running");
                StartNewThread();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
            }
        }

        private static int i = 0;
        public static void StartNewThread()
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Stating new thread " + i.ToString());

            string logFileName = @"threadlog_" + i.ToString();

            ILoggerRepository loggerRepository = LogManager.CreateRepository(logFileName + "Repository");
            ThreadContext.Properties["LogName"] = logFileName;
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(loggerRepository);
            ILog threadlogger = LogManager.GetLogger(logFileName + "Repository", "ThreadLogger");
            i++;
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ILog thdlog = threadlogger;
                while (true)
                {
                    int th = i;
                    Console.WriteLine("In new thread " + Task.CurrentId.ToString());
                    thdlog.Debug("DoWork is working in thread : " + Task.CurrentId.ToString());

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            });
      }    
}
```

Comment: log4net initially creates the log files when `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` is called, at which point `%property{LogName}` is null, so the filepath evaluates as `c:\Temp\[null].log`

Comment: Thanks @stuartd. I guess, the way I'm doing this, it's going to try to create that ThreadLogger on that first Configure in Main, as you said, even though I'm not ready to use it till I start creating threads. Any suggestions as to work around ?

Comment: If the file logger is defined in config, then log4net is going to try and create the file. It's easy to [add an appender at runtime though](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200602.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C769745@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E). Also I believe you can call `GetLogger()` [directly on the `loggerRepository` you have created](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Repository_ILoggerRepository_GetLogger.htm).